# Icing merge in middle of dough in donut.afteapr applying shrinkwrap

Tags: shrinkwrap

I'm following guru blender donut.after applying shrinkwrap I by mistake apply bevel in dough now my icing stuck in middle of dough.i can see only small part of icing in X-ray mode as well.how to adjust icing , as it's not coming out after "loose by selection".
Tia

Comment: If you've applied the bevel modifier there's usually no way back unless you have an earlier blend file backup or your undo settings allow you to go back far enough (Ctrl-Z to undo). That's why I used to make regular backups with the tutorial timestamp as part of the filename when I was following tutorials.

Comment: you probably can scale up the icing, maybe try Alt S (Shrink/Fatten)?